# android sign in page "Unfortunately app is not respinding "error

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

I am new to android i have been working on sign in page and trying to connect it to database using PHP and MySQL but it shows fatal error "Unfortunately app is not responding"

Login.php

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //Getting values 
    $username = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //Creating sql query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$username' AND password='$password'";

    //importing dbConnect.php script 
    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    //executing query
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    //fetching result
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    //if we got some result 
    if(isset($check)){
        //displaying success 
        echo "success";
    }else{
        //displaying failure
        echo "failure";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

?>

Signin.java

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent; 
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button ;
 import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
   import com.android.volley.Request;
   import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
   import com.android.volley.Response;
   import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
   import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
   import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map;

  public class Signin extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//Defining views
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
public Button bsignin;
final TextView textviewregister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewregister);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);



    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    bsignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    //bsignin = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.bsignin);



    bsignin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SigninRequest.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
    boolean loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SigninRequest.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

    //If we will get true
    if(loggedIn){
        //We will start the Profile Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Signin.this, Profile.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void login(){
    //Getting values from edit texts
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SigninRequest.LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //If we are getting success from server
                    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(SigninRequest.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                        //Creating a shared preference
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Signin.this.getSharedPreferences(SigninRequest.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                        //Adding values to editor
                        editor.putBoolean(SigninRequest.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                        editor.putString(SigninRequest.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);

                        //Saving values to editor
                        editor.apply();

                        //Starting profile activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Signin.this, Profile.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        //If the server response is not success
                        //Displaying an error message on toast
                        Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //You can handle error here if you want
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //Adding parameters to request
            params.put(SigninRequest.KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(SigninRequest.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

            //returning parameter
            return params;
        }
    };

    textviewregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Signin.this,Signup.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    //Adding the string request to the queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Calling the login function
    login();
}
```

}

SigninRequest.java

```
public class SigninRequest {
public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://localhost/Login.php/";


public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

//If server response is equal to this that means login is successful
public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "success";


public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "Bonpost";

//This would be used to store the email of current logged in user
public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "email";

//We will use this to store the boolean in sharedpreference to track user is loggedin or not
public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
enter code here
```

}

Comment: Add the stacktrace if there is a crash.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger on the Android program?

Comment: no i have not tried using debugger,

Answer (score 0):

1) The problem might be server side issue due to deprecated settings, make sure your php script uses in all files mysqli or pdo instead of the deprecated "msql"

2) Make sure all your activities are added on your manifest files.

3) Make sure your phone or testing device is connected to the same wifi as your computer.

4) If the above doesn't help, I will help rewrite your code.

*Happy Coding*

Comment: i have tried all those method back, but i am still facing the same problem